# PowerPoint 2010 (or later) - Shape position on Ribbon

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

In PowerPoint you can set a the width and height of a Shape from the ribbon:

[image: PowerPoint Ribbon shape width height]

How can I do the same with its position (x and y coordinate)?

I know I can click a billion times and set it through dialog boxes but it would make sense to set it from the ribbon like width and height. (I know that PowerPoint is of the poorest quality in Microsoft Office and its developers did not make sensible choices but maybe I am lucky and there is such a feature.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the shape, choose Format Shape. The Formatting pane opens on the right. Click the right-most icon in the pane (the one that's orange in the screenshot below). Then click the triangles to open the formatting options you want.  You can also get there more directly by clicking the "dialog launcher" below and to the right of the size options on the ribbon.

[image]